# SSRS sliders for each dataset

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, slider, scrollbar

Is there a way to add sliders for each dataset in SSRS?

For instance if I had 3 datasets, I want to have each of them have it's own integrated window that I can set it's specific length and height containing it's own sliders to scroll up and down.

In other words, when running the report, there will be one main window with it's own side scrollbar/slider. Within that window, there are going to be 3 smaller window for each dataset with their own scrollbar?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, SSRS will not do this out of the box.

SSRS is designed to build paginated reports so it will automatically expand containers to fit the contents and therefore not scroll bars will be generated.

I suspect you would have to build something to do this such as a wen page containing 4 'reports' each one in it's own frame. Alternatively PowerBI could probably do what you need but that might not be a viable option for your scenario.